# Search recursively each row on a file to another file and print the output to new file

Tags: linux, files

I need to get a listing of thousand of servers living on virtualized environment.
On a file I have something like this:

```
Name          Host
sysserver0012 btesxid432.eu.domain.com
sysserver0015 btesxid433.eu.domain.com
ldap56        essgdb56.rspc-la.domain.com
..
```

That file was generated through vCenter.
I have another file with a list of VM's which reside on different vCenters. Example:

```
sysserver0015.eu.domain.com
sysserver0050.eu.domain.com
```

I need to get the matching string from each entry on the first file and get the match on the file with all the hosts, but the thing is that on the first file you have only the hostname without the FQDN while on the complete list you do, I'd like to get a way to do the search, and if the hostname (without the full domain) is found on the second file to print out those lines only saving to a new file

So as demo on the new file generated based from the above input this will get written:
sysserver0015 btesxid433.eu.domain.com

Answer (score 1):

Or try `awk`

```
awk -F"[ .]" 'NR==FNR {SRCH[$1]; next} $1 in SRCH' file2 file1
sysserver0015 btesxid433.eu.domain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?:

```
while read a1 a2 ; do
  a3=$(grep $a1 file1.txt)
  printf "$a1 $a2 ${a3:-NO_MATCH}\n"
done <file2.txt | column -t
```

Comment: You need to set `IFS` to "." for the `read`.

Comment: @RudiC: Nope. Worked fine for me just as it is...